# How to make this T-SQL query run faster (using Group by & Case)?

Tags: t-sql, query-optimization

I have bottom SQL view on the bottom, and I would like to get some feedback how I should make this perform better.

I believe it runs slow due to Group by and Case.

Is there anything/anywhere I could make the query perform better?

```
select FacilityID,
   TransactionDate,
   sum(Amount) as Amount,
   AccountNumber as RevenueTypeID,
   (case when (case when AccountNumber like '%z%' then SUBSTRING(AccountNumber, 8, 3) else SUBSTRING(AccountNumber, 6, 3) end) = '201' then 'Medicare Part A' 
         when (case when AccountNumber like '%z%' then SUBSTRING(AccountNumber, 8, 3) else SUBSTRING(AccountNumber, 6, 3) end) = '202' then 'Medicare Part B' 
         when (case when AccountNumber like '%z%' then SUBSTRING(AccountNumber, 8, 3) else SUBSTRING(AccountNumber, 6, 3) end) = '211' then 'Medicare HMO' 
         else 'Other'
   end) as RevenueTypeDesc,
   (LastName + ', ' + FirstName) as FullName,
   Payer,
   EffectiveDate,
   (case when EffectiveDate >= DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(TransactionDate), MONTH(TransactionDate), 1) then 'Current Period' else 'Past Period' end) as CategoryDesc
from [dbo].[view_ods_revenue_journal]
where TransactionDate <= EOMONTH(getdate())
group by FacilityID,
     TransactionDate,
     AccountNumber,
     (case when (case when AccountNumber like '%z%' then SUBSTRING(AccountNumber, 8, 3) else SUBSTRING(AccountNumber, 6, 3) end) = '201' then 'Medicare Part A' 
           when (case when AccountNumber like '%z%' then SUBSTRING(AccountNumber, 8, 3) else SUBSTRING(AccountNumber, 6, 3) end) = '202' then 'Medicare Part B' 
           when (case when AccountNumber like '%z%' then SUBSTRING(AccountNumber, 8, 3) else SUBSTRING(AccountNumber, 6, 3) end) = '211' then 'Medicare HMO' 
           else 'Other'
     end),
     (LastName + ', ' + FirstName),
     Payer,
     EffectiveDate,
     (case when EffectiveDate >= DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(TransactionDate), MONTH(TransactionDate), 1) then 'Current Period' else 'Past Period' end)
```

Comment: A question on performance requires details of the tables involved, indexes/keys/constraints and the *actual* execution plan using [PasteThePlan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan). Curious if your `where` criteria actually filters any rows as presumably you don't have transactions in the future?

Comment: @Stu I am sorry. What do you mean by "where criteria actually filters any rows as presumably you don't have transactions in the future"? Thanks.

Comment: I mean `EOMONTH(getdate())` is in the future, so every date (assuming you don't have transactions dated in the future) will be less than or equal to it.

Comment: I don't see anything that stands out performancewise. All of the expressions present should evaluate in constant time. To avoid duplication of code, I would suggest calculating RevenueTypeDesc and CategoryDesc in a CROSS apply, so that the same calculated value can be referenced in the group by and select. (SQL Server likely already does this under the covers). Only other note is that your date range has no lower bound. and my guess is that for a journal table,  TransactionDate <= EOMONTH(getdate()) is likely always true. Any performance issues are likely within view_ods_revenue_journal.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
WITH    RevenueType AS
        (
            SELECT  Code    =   '201', Description  =   'Medicare Part A' UNION
            SELECT  Code    =   '202', Description  =   'Medicare Part B' UNION
            SELECT  Code    =   '211', Description  =   'Medicare HMO' 
        )
,       RevenueJournal AS
        (
            SELECT
                    FacilityID
                ,   TransactionDate
                ,   Amount
                ,   RevenueTypeID   =   AccountNumber
                ,   RevenueTypeCode =   CASE WHEN   AccountNumber LIKE  '%z%' 
                                             THEN   SUBSTRING(AccountNumber, 8, 3)
                                             ELSE   SUBSTRING(AccountNumber, 6, 3)
                                        END
                ,   FullName        =   LastName + ', ' + FirstName
                ,   Payer
                ,   EffectiveDate
                ,   CategoryDesc    =   CASE WHEN   EffectiveDate >= DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(TransactionDate), MONTH(TransactionDate), 1) 
                                             THEN   'Current Period' 
                                             ELSE   'Past Period'
                                        END
            FROM    dbo.view_ods_revenue_journal

            WHERE   TransactionDate <=  EOMONTH(GETDATE())
        )
,       RevenueJournalFinal AS
        (
            SELECT
                    FacilityID
                ,   TransactionDate
                ,   Amount
                ,   RevenueTypeID   
                ,   RevenueTypeDesc = ISNULL(T.Description, 'Other')
                ,   FullName        
                ,   Payer
                ,   EffectiveDate
                ,   CategoryDesc    
            FROM        RevenueJournal  J
            LEFT JOIN   RevenueType     T   ON T.Code = J.Code
        )                                   
                            
SELECT
        FacilityID
    ,   TransactionDate
    ,   Amount          =   SUM(Amount)
    ,   RevenueTypeID   
    ,   RevenueTypeDesc
    ,   FullName        
    ,   Payer
    ,   EffectiveDate
    ,   CategoryDesc    
FROM    RevenueJournalFinal

GROUP BY
        FacilityID
    ,   TransactionDate
    ,   RevenueTypeID
    ,   RevenueTypeDesc
    ,   FullName        
    ,   Payer
    ,   EffectiveDate
    ,   CategoryDesc
```

Comment: Tip: You might want to look at using a [table value constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/table-value-constructor-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to create the constant lookup table, e.g. `select * from ( values ( '201', 'Medicare Part A' ), ( '202', 'Medicare Part B' ), ( '211', 'Medicare HMO' ) ) as RevenueTypes( Code, Description );`. It can be used in a CTE, `join`, ... . Of course there is still that dangling `'Other'` from the OP's query.

Comment: Definitely, he needs a lookup table. i was just trying to give him an idea using a CTE on the fly.